# Select the value of a sibling row that can only be found through a parent row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I only have 1 table called Posts with 5 columns (much like StackExchange Data Explorer)

```
Id, Score, PostTypeId, ParentId, AcceptedAnswerId 
1   5      1           null      3
2   3      1           null      5
3   9      2           1         null
4   3      2           1         null
....
```

As you can see, the rows have two levels of hierarchy (Parents, Childs). Let's say **I want to select the childs** (PostTypeId = 2) and **for each one** I would like to left join the score of the **sibling** that is currently accepted by the parent. The accepted sibling Id can only be found in the AcceptedAnswerId column of the **parent** row. The parent row can be found through the ParentId of the child row I am selecting. Is there an elegant way to do this?

The expected results is the following

```
 Id, Score, AcceptedScore
 3   9      9
 4   3      9
 ....
```

My attempt (although it doesn't work and hurts my eyes as well as my brain):

```
select top 50 a.Id, a.Score, b.Score as AcceptedScore
from Posts as a
left join (
  select c.Score from Posts as c
  where c.Id = (
    select d.AcceptedAnswerId from Posts as d
    where d.Id = a.ParentId
  )
) as b
on b.ParentId = a.ParentId 
where a.PostTypeId = 2
```

The error I'm getting:

```
The multi-part identifier "a.ParentId" could not be bound. Invalid column name 'ParentId'.
```

Comment: what is the expected result for given data sample?

Comment: edited question to add the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one that works:

```
SELECT p1.Id, p1.Score, p3.Score AS AcceptedScore
FROM Posts p1 LEFT JOIN Posts p2
  ON p1.ParentId = p2.Id LEFT JOIN Posts p3
  ON p2.AcceptedAnswerId = p3.Id
WHERE p1.PostTypeId = 2
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2abd3/3)